# can not attach visual studio code to remote container

Tags: visual-studio-code

Error running command remote-containers.attachToRunningContainerFromViewlet: Shell server failed: Error: spawn C:\Users\xxx.ssh\config ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21). This is likely caused by the extension that contributes remote-containers.attachToRunningContainerFromViewlet.

Version: 1.68.1 (user setup)

Commit: 30d9c6cd9483b2cc586687151bcbcd635f373630

Date: 2022-06-14T12:48:58.283Z

Electron: 17.4.7

Chromium: 98.0.4758.141

Node.js: 16.13.0

V8: 9.8.177.13-electron.0

OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044

By the way, I can attach to local container

Comment: I am not sure if the extension is supposed to be able to connect to remote containers, it will probably not be secure. You could set up an ssh server on the remote container, pass the port through to the host and connect through the vscode ssh extension